# Correct function definition for optional parameters of a SELECT query in Python using psycopg2 with POSTGRESQL

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I want to SELECT from my PostgreSQL database using optional filter parameters in a function, but am struggling to get the syntax right.

```
def search(title: str = '', author: str = "", year: int, isbn: int):
    conn = psycopg2.connect(
        " dbname='mydb' user='postgres' password='pwd' host='localhost' port='5432' ")
    curs = conn.cursor()
    curs.execute("SELECT * FROM book WHERE title=? OR author=? OR year=? OR isbn=?",
                 (title, author, year, isbn))
    rows = curs.fetchall()
    conn.close()
    return rows
```

I then want to search by passing only one parameter (author name) to the function, and have the SELECT-statement be able to ignore/skip the fields that have not been passed. When I execute

```
print(search(author="John"))
```

The output is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "backend.py", line 48, in <module>
    print(search(author="John"))
  File "backend.py", line 39, in search
    (title, author, year, isbn))
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedFunction: operator does not exist: text =?
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM book WHERE title=? OR author=? OR year=? OR is...
                                      ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type. You might need to add an explicit type cast.
```

I understand this relates to a mismatch between the datatype of the SELECT-statement and the database column type, and that the error reflects that there is no = operator for comparing those two data types. But how do I define my function parameters and the SELECT statement to get my query to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

psycopg2 uses `%s` as the placeholder for string substitution, not `?`.  Try changing the ? to %s and it should work.

Edit:
@Parfait brought up a good point about your where logic.  Changing ? to %s will fix your syntax error, but still won't fix the logic.  One common way of handling this is to default all of your parameters to `None` and change your query to something like this:

```
curs.execute("""
    SELECT * FROM BOOK
    WHERE (title = %(title)s OR %(title)s IS NULL)
      AND (author = %(author)s OR %(author)s IS NULL)
      AND (year = %(year)s OR %(year)s IS NULL)
      AND (isbn = %(isbn)s OR %(isbn)s IS NULL)""",
    {"title": title, "author": author, "year": year, "isbn": isbn})
```

This is not the most performant method, but it's probably the simplest.

Comment: Thanks. Feeling a bit silly now - I previously had an sqlite database.

Comment: My logic seems fine to me, at least it returns the correct results. Avoiding posting the code and results here since it's not intended to go in comments.

Comment: @oldnoob ... that would be the case if all your string columns do not ever maintain empty values. Recall zero length strings, `''`, is not the same as `NULL`.

Comment: After setting the `author` field of a row to `NULL` my query was still able to both include and exclude that row searching with various combinations of parameters, returning `None` for that specific field.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, consider passing `None` as default which translates to `NULL` and use SQL's `COALESCE` to select the first not null value. If params are `None`, then the columns in query will equal each other which is essentially applying no filter.

```
def search(title = None, author = None, year = None, isbn = None):
    conn = psycopg2.connect(
        " dbname='mydb' user='postgres' password='pwd' host='localhost' port='5432' ")

    sql = """SELECT * FROM book 
             WHERE COALESCE(title, 'N/A') = COALESCE(%s, title, 'N/A')
               AND COALESCE(author, 'N/A') = COALESCE(%s, author, 'N/A')
               AND COALESCE(year, -1) = COALESCE(%s, year, -1) 
               AND COALESCE(isbn, -1) = COALESCE(%s, isbn, -1)
          """

    curs = conn.cursor()
    curs.execute(sql, (title, author, year, isbn))
    rows = curs.fetchall()
    conn.close()

    return rows
```

Comment: Wouldn't this require a not null constraint on each column or use `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM` instead of `=`?

Comment: @Jeremy, good point! `COALESCE` should be on both sides of equation.